# Django: Inject form validation on ModelForm, not Model

Tags: django, django-forms, django-validation

**Question:** Is there a way to inject form field validation on the `ModelForm` instead of the `Model`?

**Justification:** I have three `ModelForm`'s that update the same `Model` instance, which have default conditions for `blank`. I should have designed three different Models for each form, but I'm to far in to make a change.

Please assist!

Thanks,
Neel

Comment: Yes, by implementing the `clean_fieldname` functions. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: Thanks Willem, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ModelForm](https://kite.com/python/docs/django.forms.models.ModelForm) is a kind of Form (as it inherits from BaseForm), so you can use Form field validation methods to do it because `clean()` method is inheried from BaseForm. So for field named `foo` you use clean_foo() method to do cleanup

Answer (score 1):

leotrubach's answer is the way to go, I just want to add that [the django documentation on the subject](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/) is a good read.